# High CPU load when running Java program

Tags: java, cpu

Ive found several posts containing the same issue, yet I haven't been able to conduct an answer out of these posts. Im not very familiar with looking of thread dump and such, so in case possible it would be nice to get a detailed answer of what I should do. The problem is the following:

As a group project we're asked to program 4 AI bots in an eclipse plugin called GOAL. Now most of you wont be familiar with this program as it is a programming language created by the proffessors of the University. However, the program seems to be running fine on the laptops my fellow students have. They dont have any problem running it. These processors typically are i7 4740m, which run at clocking speed of approximately 2.5Ghz.

When I try to run the program on my desktop however, I find the processer usage at a 100%. Therefor I'm in no state to run the program fluently. I have an I-5 6500 which has about 3.2Ghz. Now I know the I-7 is better for multithreading, but I feel as if my i-5 should be able to run this program effortlessly.

Does anyone have any explaining why my processor doesnt seem capable of handling this, or better yet. A solution in where it can.

Comment: We don't know the program, how would we know how you can solve this?

Comment: This can be related to the OS you're running, to the available memory you have, to the JVM you're using, and of course, as randy said, to the program itself. It's impossible to answer your question given the information you're provided.

Comment: The oracle jdk ships with a [profiler called jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html). Just start it, double- or right-click on the node that represents the app you want to profile, select "sample" and then "CPU"; after some time press the "snapshot" button. Should give you a quick overview of what's eating the cpu time.